# Left join with distinct and calculate column value

Tags: c#, sql, group-by, db2, left-join

I have two tables like which I would like to join and get the result as shown below

Table 1

```
JobNO       |       JobMovRefNo
---------------------------------
123         |   1
456         |   1
789         |   1
```

Table 2

```
JobNO       |   Arrived
---------------------------------
123         |   y
123         |   y
123         |   n
456         |   y
456         |   y
```

Result Table

```
JobNO       |   Arrived
---------------------------------
123         |   n
456         |   y
789         |   n
```

I tried a left join with group by but I am getting duplicate records. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not so clear what a logic behind. Is arrived should to show last status?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `left join` and aggregate before joining

```
select *
from table1 t1 left join
     (select jobno, min(arrived) as arrived
      from table2 t2
      group by jobno
     ) t2
     using (jobno);
```

You have not explained your logic, but you seem to want the minimum value of `arrived` on each row, which is what this does.

EDIT:

Very old versions of DB2 don't support `USING`.  This can also be written as:

```
select t1.*, coalesce(t2.arrived, 'n') as arrived
from table1 t1 left join
     (select jobno, min(arrived) as arrived
      from table2 t2
      group by jobno
     ) t2
     on t2.jobno = t1.jobno;
```

Comment: `group by jobno`

Comment: @GORDON -Thanks for your answer. I quickly tried this, I am using DB2 by the way and I get an error 'column or global variable t2 not found

Comment: @Abe . . . I fixed the tag on your question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Thanks once again, I am getting the data however getting some nulls for jobno 789. I would like it to be a 'n'. Any thoughts?

Comment: @GordonLinoff  -  Can you tell me how to who count of everything which is arrived i.e 'y' in my example?

Comment: Do you want counts by jobs or rows in the second table?  It might be better to ask a new question.

Comment: FYI Db2 has supported `USING` in joins since 11.1   https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0059207.html

Comment: @PaulVernon . . . I will say that I expended some effort looking for appropriate documentation and it wasn't easy to find.  I fixed the answer.

Answer (score 1):

this is my solution.
I used postgreSQL; hope it works with your dbms.

```
select 
    t1.jobno,
    min(CASE WHEN t2.arrived IS NULL THEN 'n' ELSE t2.arrived END) as arrived
from table1 t1 left join table2 t2 on t1.jobno = t2.jobno  
group by t1.jobno
order by t1.jobno
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a `LEFT JOIN`, `GROUP BY`. Use `coalesce` to get 'n' for jobno's not existing in table2.

```
select t1.jobno, coalesce(min(t2.arrived), 'n')
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t1.jobno = t2.jobno
group by t1.jobno
```